# Opening camera in multiple program in openCV

Tags: opencv, parallel-processing, webcam, distributed-computing, low-latency

How can I open a single webcam in multiple programs written in **`openCV`** simultaneously. Btw I have attached 3 webcams and all are working fine in any single program of `openCV`, **but why** two program can't use them both, simultaneously?

Is this a restriction or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, <sub>this is an intention to restrict</sub>

Why? The conceptual view is related to the hardware control layer. Operating system assumes, there are some peripherals, that can be used on-demand, but keeps their context-of-use non-share-able.

As an example, one may assume a USB-mouse. While it can be used within several processes, some reasoning told the architects, it would not be the case one mouse should feed events into more than one-<sub>`( window )`-framed</sub> -context <sub>( Yes, right, a.k.a. process )</sub>

Some other peripherals are even instances of both an `EventSENSOR` and an `EventCOLLECTOR`, USB-Cameras for example can receive and process signals from operating system to re-adjust their physical state ( Pan-Tilt-Zoom as an example ).

The more obvious becomes the 1:1 relation assumption, which is something we may sometimes wish not to have hardcoded there. On the other hand, what would the poor device do, if one process instructs it **`go-left`** and another **`go-right`** at the same time?

Similarly, who would be happy if one USB-mouse will send it's motion and other MMI-interaction events to all currently running processes? At least Drag&Drop UI-navigation policy will become a funny lottery.

### Yes, <sub>there is a workaround</sub>

A simplest "**just-enough**" scenario includes **`aCameraControllerPROCESS`** which keeps the 1:1 relation with USB-device and has the visual **`data`**-acquisition responsibility. Here nanoseconds matter, so do not spend any `CPU_CLK` on anything other but on moving bytes into a buffer. All other processing shall be left on `aVisualDataViewConsumerPROCESS` where **`openCV`** may <sub>( and **will** )</sub> spend tens and hundreds microseconds on it's own.

[image: Multi-process distributed openCV processing of visual-<code>data</code>]

Plus it has a **communication / service provisioning part**, which allows other distributed processes, access the acquired visual `data` in parallel manner ( in a non-blocking, concurrent view manner, which is a must for distributed soft-real-time processing ).

If one's architecture requires more features or alternatives, this layered approach allows one to add features while retaining both the control and performance overheads within acceptable envelopes.

A good implementation may remain quite smart, fast, low-latency and slim (resources-wise), if one uses **`ZeroMQ`** with it's Zero-Copy **`inproc:`** <sup>virtually abstract</sup> transport class, where one does lose an almost Zero-Latency as a cost of the trick, but gains an immense power of having a robust, massively-distribute-able  <sub>one may scale-out beyond one, two, dozen, thousands, ... you name it ... hosts for free</sub>