# Single Camera access by two processes at the same time

Tags: graphics, parallel-processing, computer-vision

I want to use one Camera for two processes / threads, e.g.
**a**) live streaming and
**b**) image processing at the same time.

### Use Case:

Application, which can handle multiple request, based on a user request.
a) User can request – Detect cam-1 and do a Live streaming
b) Later, user can request – Detect Motion / Image processing using the same cam-1, while process (a) is doing the live streaming.

Challenge I see to access same camera by 2 different process at the same time, is there way to reroute the data / pointers of Cam data to different process ?

Note: OS -Windows

Any help will be appreciated !!
Regards, AK

Comment: Not sure as to what libraries/toolsets you are using, but it is likely that you will need to duplicate your incoming video streaming in one thread and pass a copy of that data to the others. Depending on your library, duplicate the data structure that gives you access to the cameras feed/pixel values/video frames.

Comment: Thanks, am using OpenCV, I am avoiding to save the data into disk, because its on demand multiple request.

Answer (score 0):

### Well, doable. But ..

Given the said above, there are few things to respect once designing the target software approach. One of these is a fact, the camera is a device, which restricts it to have a single "commander-in-charge", rather than permiting to have a shizophrenic "duty" under several concurrent bosses.

This sais, the solution is in smarter-design of the acquired data-stream, this could be delivered into several concurrent consuming-processes.

[image]

For more hints on such a design concept, [**read this Answer** to a similarly motivated Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712899)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to let two threads access the camera at the same time.

If the driver allows it, you may work with multiple buffers, used in a round-robin fashion to store the live stream. Their content can be continuously sent to the display, but when desired you can leave one on the side and reserve it to allow for longer processing.

If this is not possible, you can copy every desired image to a processing buffer when needed.

If your system must be very responsive and process the images in real-time, there is probably no need for two threads !

---

In any case, if you are working with two threads, there is no need to "reroute the pointers", you simply let the threads access the buffers.

If they are processes rather than threads, then you can establish the buffers in a shared memory section.